# How do change the value for specific user using SQL?

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

I want to change the age for users named 'Mike' and add 5 to their age.

I am trying the `update` statement, but it is not working. Is there any other way other than `update` to do this?

```
UPDATE Table1 
SET [Age] = '+3' 
WHERE UserName = 'Mike'
```

The result looks like this:

```
    UserName       Age           
1      John        21
2      Mike        18
3      Ben         20
4      Mike        17
```

I want it to look like this:

```
     UserName      Age            
1      John        21
2      Mike        23
3      Ben         20
4      Mike        22
```

Comment: Try `Set Age = Age + 5`

Comment: The absolute best solution would be to store birthdate instead and calculate the age when you need it. When you store a persons age the data is stale as soon as you set a value.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE Table1 SET [Age] = [Age] +3 WHERE UserName = 'Mike'
```

Comment: So exactly the same as the other two answers, but with `+3` instead of `+5`?

Comment: @lebelinoz I wrote 3 because that was the number in the OP's example.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the **correct syntax** and it should work just fine:

```
UPDATE Table1 
SET [Age] = [Age] + 5 
WHERE UserName = 'Mike'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you're after:

First look:

```
SELECT [Age]+5, *
FROM Table1  T
WHERE UserName = 'Mike'
```

Then Update

```
UPDATE T SET [Age] = [Age]+5
FROM Table1  T
WHERE UserName = 'Mike'
```